# Fetch prices from Google Play, in-app-purchases

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I would like to get the prices for my in app items directly from Google Play, not hard coded. I found the following function

```
public String getPricesDev() throws RemoteException, JSONException{

    String packageName = mContext.getPackageName();
    ArrayList<String> skuList = new ArrayList<String>();
    skuList.add("batforerproven.permanent.cat1"); //Is this correct? Name of products?
    skuList.add("batforerproven.permanent.cat2");

    Bundle querySkus = new Bundle();
    querySkus.putStringArrayList("ITEM_ID_LIST", skuList);

    Bundle skuDetails = mService.getSkuDetails(3,packageName, ITEM_TYPE_INAPP, querySkus);

    int response = skuDetails.getInt("RESPONSE_CODE");
    if (response == 0) {
        ArrayList<String> responseList 
        = skuDetails.getStringArrayList("DETAILS_LIST");

        for (String thisResponse : responseList) {
            JSONObject object = new JSONObject(thisResponse);
            String sku = object.getString("productId");
            String price = object.getString("price");

            if(sku.contains("batforerproven.permanent.cat2")) return price; 

        }
    } 
    return "Not found";
}
```

The problem is that I try to use this code before the Service is binded. (mService is null)

In my onCreate() I do some UI-setup, then I call

```
mIabHelper = new IabHelper(this, base64EncodedPublicKey);

    mIabHelper.startSetup(new IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener() {
        public void onIabSetupFinished(IabResult result) 
        {
            if (!result.isSuccess()) {
                Toast.makeText(BuyExtras.this, "Feil ved kobling mot Google Play.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {             
                mIabHelper.queryInventoryAsync(mReceivedInventoryListener);
            }
        }
    });
```

And then I try to call the `mIabHelper.getPricesDev()`, but it results in null pointer, due to mService is null...

What functions should I call to set up the service?

Comment: Did you write permissions to the manifest?

Comment: Yes, everything is working, but now I have hard-coded price on the buy-buttons...
Clicking the buttons obviously sets up the service (from launchPurchaseFlow()?), but I want to get the prices before the purchases...

Comment: Here's how it works: you call mIabHelper.startSetup in onCreate and in listener as you wrote you querying inventory and only after that in mReceivedInventoryListener you have inventory and you can do like that inventory.getSkuDetails().getPrice() and update UI

Comment: Ok, will give it a try

Comment: I tried getPrice() in onQueryInventoryFinished(), which gave the correct price. But the inventory is only the products already bought?
I would like to get the prices + description for all products...

Comment: inventory contains every available items and every price. You need iterate over inventory.mSkuMap map and get all prices and descriptions you need

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by doing a simple change in my exsisting code..
What I did was to change

```
mIabHelper.queryInventoryAsync(mReceivedInventoryListener);
```

to

```
ArrayList<String> additionalSkuList = new ArrayList<String>();
additionalSkuList.add(ITEM_CAT_1);
additionalSkuList.add(ITEM_CAT_2);
additionalSkuList.add(ITEM_CAT_3);
additionalSkuList.add(ITEM_PREMIUM);
mIabHelper.queryInventoryAsync(true, additionalSkuList, mQueryFinishedListener);
```

And in the listener, I added

```
cat1Desc.setText(inventory.getSkuDetails(ITEM_CAT_1).getDescription());
cat2Desc.setText(inventory.getSkuDetails(ITEM_CAT_2).getDescription());
cat3Desc.setText(inventory.getSkuDetails(ITEM_CAT_3).getDescription());
PremiumDesc.setText(inventory.getSkuDetails(ITEM_PREMIUM).getDescription());

buyCat1Btn.setText(inventory.getSkuDetails(ITEM_CAT_1).getPrice());
buyCat2Btn.setText(inventory.getSkuDetails(ITEM_CAT_2).getPrice());
buyCat3Btn.setText(inventory.getSkuDetails(ITEM_CAT_3).getPrice());
buyPremiumBtn.setText(inventory.getSkuDetails(ITEM_PREMIUM).getPrice());
```